Setting up Django. I can't install psycopg2 in a virtual environment. This is what the terminal outputs
Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.9.10.tar.gz (385 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [21 lines of output]
running egg_info
writing psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
  Error: pg_config executable not found.
 
  pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
  containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
  option:
 
      python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
 
  or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
 
  If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
  'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
 
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
 
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
The makemigrations command will not run without this library.

Do you have PostgreSQL installed ?
if yes, check the pg_config location in :

For linux : /usr/pgsql-/bin/pg_config
For windows : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL<version>\bin\pg_config.exe

Then, update the PATH :

For linux : export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/pg_config/executable

Otherwise, you can try :
sudo apt install libpq-dev python3-dev
sudo apt install build-essential

